# How to design database tables that should be adding more tables?

Tags: database

I think there's already a specific topic for this but I don't know the keyword for it. Anyway what's the best database design for something that does not follow the general rule on your table?

For example, I have an employee database.  It has their address, their nicknames and etc. How do you implement dependents, since all employees will have a different number of dependents.

Should I just put like 5 columns for dependents or is there a more applicable design for this stuff?

Comment: What do u mean by dependents ?

Comment: the employee children ,wife or parents

Comment: Store them in a separate table, and reference the owning employee via a relation? And no, you never create multiple columns for attributes of which an entry can have multiple, that always becomes an own table. Just Google for "normal form".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding you should use the concept of Normalization while designing the Database/Table Structure.

Database Normalisation is a technique of organizing the data in the database. Normalization is a systematic approach of decomposing tables to eliminate data redundancy and undesirable characteristics like Insertion, Update and Deletion Anamolies. Its also the process of organizing the **columns (attributes)** and **tables (relations)** of a relational database.

Create  a main table with Some Primary Key ID and its dependent values to be stored in other tables using primary Foreign key Concept.

Also for different forms of Normalization and additional information check this simple [tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html)